# Sorting matrix by even numbers in rows

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, numbers, integer

Okay, so I'm just starting to use this site, and I know my title is a bit confusing, but I will try to explain it here as best as I can. So I have to take a matrix from the input, count even and odd numbers in each row, then write the matrix with rows that have more even numbers first. Example:

Input:

3 3 // Dimensions

1 2 3 // Elemets

4 5 6

7 8 9

Output:

1 2 3 // Original matrix

4 5 6

7 8 9

1 2 // Number of even and odd elements in each row

2 1

1 2

4 5 6 // Matrix sorted by even numbers in rows

1 2 3

7 8 9

I did everything except figuring out how to write out the final matrix. Any help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main() {

    int row, column, temp, count;
    int even[100], odd[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        even[i] = odd[i] = 0;

    scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
    count = row;

    int* matrix = (int*)malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            scanf("%d", &*(matrix + i * column + j));

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            printf("%d ", *(matrix + i * column + j));
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            temp = *(matrix + i * column + j);
            if (temp % 2 == 0)
                even[i]++;
            else odd[i]++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", even[i], odd[I]);


    return 0;
}
```

If there are some errors with variable names, I was translating most of them here directly, so maybe I missed some of them, sorry in advance.

Comment: Do you actually want to sort the matrix, or do you just want to print the rows in sorted order? That might seem like a meaningless distinction, but it makes a huge difference in the amount of code you have to write.

Comment: Only print out, it doesn't need to be sorted that way, sorry I expressed myself badly.

Comment: I thought of doing it by changing the loop counter by the number of the row, but I couldn't find the way to do it so that it works.

Comment: Start by finding the maximum value in the `even` array, let's call that value `maxEven`. Then write a loop `for (int e = maxEven; e >= 0; e--)`. Inside that loop, write another loop that goes through all the rows. Any row that has `even[i] == e` gets printed.

Comment: Wow, that is a very smart and easy solution. Thank you very much I will try it :)

Comment: Glad to help, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `swap` function first, then compare the even value between the rows.

```
// Swap 2 elements
void swap_elt(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

// swap row m and row n
void swap(int *matrix, int m, int n, int column) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j)
    {
        swap_elt(matrix + m * column + j, matrix + n * column + j);
    }
    return;
}
```

The for loop for compare the even value between the rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < count; j++)
        {
            if (even[i] < even[j]) {
                swap(matrix, i, j, column);
            }
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
3 3 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
1 2
2 1
1 2
4 5 6 
1 2 3 
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't say that this is 100% the answer but I tried my best (Sorry that my solution is a little different, I think I do understand your question but I can't make my answer better. Edit: I also include user3386109's idea too (at the bottom of my answer).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int row, col;
    scanf ("%d %d%*c", &row, &col);

    int mtx[row][col];
    for (int x=0; x<row; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<col; y++) scanf ("%d%*c", &mtx[x][y]);
    }

    //Printing the original matrix
    for (int x=0; x<row; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<col; y++)
        {
            if (y) printf (" %d", mtx[x][y]);
            else printf ("%d", mtx[x][y]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    int odd[row], even[row];            //Make a var to store odd/even value each row
    for (int x=0; x<row; x++)
    {
        odd[x]=even[x]=0;               //Set to 0 before doing an operation, for safety
        for (int y=0; y<col; y++)
        {
            if (mtx[x][y]%2) odd[x]++;  //If it is odd, odd[which_row] incremented
            else even[x]++;             //Else, even gets incremented
        }
        printf ("%d %d\n", even[x], odd[x]);
    }

    int temp;
    for (int x=0; x<row-1; x++)
    {
        for (int y=x+1; y<row; y++)
        {
            if (even[x]<even[y])            //Same "concept" like bubble sort
            {
                for (int z=0; z<col; z++)
                {
                    temp=mtx[x][z];         //Swapping the content of the matrix
                    mtx[x][z]=mtx[y][z];
                    mtx[y][z]=temp;
                }
                temp=even[x];               //Swap the value of even[x]
                even[x]=even[y];
                even[y]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //Print the result
    for (int x=0; x<row; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<col; y++)
        {
            if (y) printf (" %d", mtx[x][y]);
            else printf ("%d", mtx[x][y]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample IO:

```
3 3
1 3 5
7 4 6
2 9 3
1 3 5
7 4 6
2 9 3
0 3
2 1
1 2
7 4 6
2 9 3
1 3 5
```

user3386109's idea:

```
for (int x=maxEven; x>=0; x--)
{
    for (int y=0; y<row; y++)
    {
        if (even[y]==x)
        {
            for (int z=0; z<col; z++)
            {
                if (z) printf (" %d", mtx[y][z]);
                else printf ("%d", mtx[y][z]);
            }
            printf ("\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```